# How to run jest on files not ending in .test.js or .spec.js?

Tags: jestjs

I have files `tests/foo.js` `tests/bar.js`. When I run `jest tests/foo.js` or `jest tests/*.js`, no test is run. How do I run test on files not ending in `.test.js`?

Answer (score 2):

`Jest` uses [`testMatch`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testmatch-array-string) to find tests:

> By default it looks for `.js`, `.jsx`, `.ts` and `.tsx` files inside of `__tests__` folders, as well as any files with a suffix of `.test` or `.spec` (e.g. `Component.test.js` or `Component.spec.js`). It will also find files called `test.js` or `spec.js`.

In your case you can set `testMatch` to the following:

```
testMatch: [ "**/tests/**/*.[jt]s?(x)" ]
```

...and it should find the tests you have created in your `tests` folder.

Comment: haha, no activity for 18 hours and then two of us answer simultaneously

Answer (score 1):

You can define the patterns jest uses to detect test files through the [testRegex](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testregex-string-array-string) or [testMatch](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testmatch-array-string) options.